# Construction of an explicit series of meromorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to construct an explicit series of meromorphic functions that converges locally uniformly on the unit disk, and such that it has poles of first order at the points $a_k:=\frac{k-1}{k}$ with residue $1$, with $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

My attempt was to modify the proof of Mittag-Leffler's theorem I have recently seen in my course of complex analysis, i.e., I considered the family of closed disks $$D_{k}:=D\left( 0,a_k\right):=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\, |z|\leq a_k\right\}$$
and the functions $f_k(z)=\frac{1}{z-a_k}$. Then I propose the series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k-F_k, $$
where $F_k$ is a Taylor polynomial of order enough large of $f_k$ such that I can be sure about the convergence using the comparison test.

Is it completely good?

Is there another more convenient way to procedure?